ls -u and find -atime show different access times for some files. Which is correct?
find -atime -2 shows about 1 dozen files accessed less than 2 days ago, but ls -u shows them all with access times of Jun 20 2023. What gives?
I was looking to see which files on an external hard drive had been accessed within a certain time period.
